# Why shared libraries between microservices are bad?

Tags: interface, architecture, shared-libraries, microservices, distributed-computing

Sam Newman states in his book *Building Microservices*

> The evils of too much coupling between services are far worse than the problems caused by code duplication

I just don't understand how the shared code between the services is evil. Does the author mean the *service boundaries themselves* are poorly designed if a need for a shared library emerges, or does he really mean I should duplicate the code in the case of common business logic dependency? I don't see what that solves.

Let's say I have a shared library of entities common to two services. The common domain objects for two services may smell, but another service is the GUI to tweak the state of those entities, another is an interface for other services to poll the state for their purpose. Same domain, different function.

Now, if the shared knowledge changes, I would have to rebuild and deploy both services regardless of the common code being an external dependency or duplicated across the services. Generally, same concerns all the cases for two services depending of the same article of the business logic. In this case, I see only harm of duplication of the code, reducing the cohesion of the system.

Of course, *diverging* from the shared knowledge may cause headaches in the case of shared library, but even this could be solved with inheritance, composition and clever use of abstractions.

So, what does Sam mean by saying code duplication is better than too much coupling via shared libraries?

Answer (score 35):

> The evils of too much coupling between services are far worse than the problems caused by code duplication

The author is very unspecific when he uses the generic word "coupling". I would agree with certain types of coupling being a strict no-no (like sharing databases or using internal interfaces). However the use of common libraries is not one of those. For example if you develop two micro services using golang you already have a shared dependency (towards golang's basic libraries). The same applies to libraries that you develop yourself for sharing purpose. Just pay attention to the following points:

- Treat libraries that are shared like you would dependencies to 3rd party entities.
- Make sure each component / library / service has a distinct business purpose.
- Version them correctly and leave the decision which version of the library to use to the corresponding micro service teams.
- Set up responsibilities for development and testing of shared libraries separately from the micro services teams.

Don't forget - The microservices architectural style is not so much focusing on code organization or internal design patterns, but on the larger organizational and process relevant aspects to allow scaling application architectures, organizations and deployments. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48678494/7803650) for an overview.

Answer (score 17):

**Short**

The core concept of the microservice architecture is that microservices have their independent development-release cycles. "Shared libraries" undermining this.

**Longer**

From my own experience, it's very important to keep microservices isolated and independent as much as possible. *Isolation* is basically about being able to release & **deploy** the service independently of any other services most of the time.
In other words its something like:

- you build a new version of a service
- you release it (after tests)
- you deploy it into production
- **you have not caused the deployment cascade of your whole environment**.

**"Shared libraries"** in my definition those libraries, do hinder you to do so.

---

It's "funny" how "Shared Libraries" poison your architecture:

> *Oh we have a User object! Let's reuse it everywhere!*

This leads to a "shared library" for the whole enterprise and starts to undermine *Bounded Contexts* (DDD), forces you to dependent on one technology

> *we already have this shared library with TDOs you need, written in
> java...*

Repeating myself. The new version of this kind of shared libs will affect all services and complicate your deployments up to very fragile setups. The consequence is at some point, that nobody trusts himself to develop the next releases of the common shared library or everyone fears the big-bang releases.

All of this just for the sake of "Don't repeat yourself"? - This is not worth it (My experience proves it). T
The shared compromised "User" object is very seldom better than several focused User objects in the particular Microservices in the praxis.

However, there is never a silver bullet and Sam gives us only a guideline and advice (a heuristic if you like) based on his projects.

**My take**

I can give you my experience. Don't start a microservice project with reasoning about shared libraries. Just don't do them in the beginning and accept some code repetition between services. Invest time in DDD and the quality of your Domain Objects and Service Boundaries. Learn on the way what are stable parts and what evolves fast.

Once you or your team gained enough insides you can refactor some parts to libraries. Such refactoring is usually very cheap in comparison to the reverse approach.

And these libraries should probably cover some boilerplate code and be focussed on one task - have several of them, not one *common-lib-for- everything* In the [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48961173/504913) *Oswin Noetzelmann* gave some advice on how to proceed. Taking his approach to the maximum would lead to good and focused libraries and not toxic "shared libraries"

Answer (score 6):

Good example of tight coupling where duplication would be acceptable can be shared library defining interface/DTOs between services. In particular using the same classes/structs to serialize/deserialize data.

Let's say you have two services - A and B - they both may accept slightly different but overall almost same looking JSON input.

It would be tempting to make one DTO describing common keys, also including the very few ones used by service A and service B as a shared library.

For some time system works fine. Both services add shared library as dependency, build and run properly.

With time, though, service A requires some additional data that would change the structure of JSON where is was the same before. As a result you can't use the same classes/structs to deserialize the JSON for both services at the same time - the change is needed for service A, but then service B won't be able to deserialize the data.

You must change shared library, add new feature to service A and rebuild it, then rebuild service B to adjust it to new version of shared library even though no logic has been changed there.

Now, would you have the DTOs defined separately, internally, for both services from the very beginning, later on, their contracts could evolve separately and safely in any direction you could imagine. Sure, at first it might have looked smelly to keep almost the same DTOs in both services but on the long run it gives you a freedom of change.

At the end of the day, (micro)services don't differ that much from monolith. Separation of concerns and isolation are critical. Some dependencies can't be avoided (language, framework, etc.) but before you introduce any additional dependency by yourself think twice about future implications.

I'd rather follow given advice - duplicate DTOs and avoid shared code unless you can't avoid it. It has bitten me in the past. Above scenario is trivial one, but it may be much more nuanced and affect much more services. Unfortunately it hits you only after some time, so the impact may be big.

Comment: duplicate DTOs -yes; avoid shared code - depends if the code just looks the same, or common by nature of it’s functionality. If you have some Common utility class( e.g. string manipulation) share it instead of duplication

Comment: If you have some code that's not business related (ex. implementation of commonly known algo) probably you're right. Make a library with proper versioning and attach it as any other dependency. Also look around, someone may have implemented it already. Even if it's business related but mature enough and not going to change any time soon, go ahead. Otherwise, I'd rather duplicate. Definitely I'd avoid, sharing the same packages if you happen to work with multirepo environment, though.

Comment: How would adding additional fields break the deserialization ? Aren’t new fields ignored? Also deleting fields clearly should not be done as long as there are consumers. What are some examples of changes that can actually break the existing consumers?

Answer (score 2):

There are no absolute answer with this. You'll always find an example for a reasonable exception to the rule. We should take this as 'guidelines'.

With that being said, yes coupling between services is something to avoid and a shared library is a warning alarm for coupling.

As other answers have explained, microservices lifecycles should be independant.
And as for your example, I think it strongly depends on what kind of logic / responsibilities does the library have.

If it is business logic, something is odd. Maybe you need to split the library in different libraries with different responsibilities, if that responsability is unique and can't be splited, you should wonder if those two services should be only one. And if that library has business logic that feels weird on those two services, most likely that library should be a service in his own right.

Answer (score -4):

Each microservice is autonomous so executables will have its own copy of shared libraries so there is no coupling with shared library?
Spring Boot, packages language run time also in package of microservice
Nothing is shared even runtime so I don't see problem in using library or common package in microservice
If shared library creates coupling in Microservice then using same languages in different Microservice also a problem?
I was also confused while reading "Building Microservices" by Sam Newman

Comment: you missed the point. every time you need to update code/logic in the shared lib, you will need to rebuild, package and redeploy EVERY (micro)service that uses it, which means microservices are not free to evolve on their own because they all depend on a library/pkg that is also used by the other services.

You will have basically coupled the microservices together into a same "deployment unit" now.